# why there is no difference in render after denoise is on?

Tags: rendering

Why there is no difference even though denoise is on? Am I doing something wrong?
The only difference (very minor), I can see is on the reflection of glass at bottom. Also, I don't see it as a good quality render, any suggestion to improve are welcomed.
Render Settings are:
GPU ENabled
Tiles 256 x 256
Sampling: 250
Denoising: Open Image

The first image is with denoising on.
[image]

This image is with denoise off:
[image: Denoise off in render]
However, when I see viewport with denoising off, I see much noise!
[image: viewport image with denoise off]

Comment: In 2.9 versions denoising is enabled by default... I'd suggest share your settings and version of blender.

Comment: I am using 2.9 and I was able to check and uncheck denoising too. I shared most of the settings. Resolution was 960*1020

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give you a subtle hint of one possibility why this might happen:

[image]

What you may have noticed in the picture is that there are different sampling settings for the render and the viewport.

> ...but what could be the reason for having the same result with "denoising"on and off?

This might be when you take a clean image rendered with enough samples for it not to have much noise and try to denoise it. The difference is minimal in that case because the denoiser does not have much noise to remove. In your specific case the difference is there and I would not even call it that small. Let's actually look for the difference in the images you have provided for a minute:

[image]

Comment: but what could be the reason for having the same result with "denoising"on and off? Yes, for the viewport thing you are right. I tested :)

Comment: There is a difference. See the updated answer with a gif.